# Converting an VBA Macro to Google Sheets

Tags: excel, vba, google-sheets

Yesterday I started using VBA and writhed down a macro with some help.
Today, with a big facepalm, I realized that Google Sheet, which is the tool we are working with in my office, doesn't support VBA.

The VBA macro is the one below

```
Sub Macroname()
   Cells(ActiveCell.Row, Day(Date) + 3).Value = Cells(ActiveCell.Row, Day(Date) + 3).Value + 1
End Sub
```

Basically what the macro does is to increments the value of the cell associated with the right day by 1.

Any help is appreciated! Have a good week end to everyone!

Edit: while waiting for some help, I'm looking around the G.S. helps to see some tutorials

Comment: Hi and welcome! What exactly do you want help with? Its important on this site that questions are kept focussed. Please read [this](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: What I was looking for is an equivalent to the macro I posted.

The VBA macro works this way: it takes my selected row and the day date as column to pick the cell, then it reads the value in that cell and +1 it, giving the new value in the same cell.

Answer (score 1):

The following code shall add a day to your date based on input range. You need to modify the range to desired cells. Hopes this helps you out.

```js
function addday() {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  var currdate = new Date();
  currdate = ss.getRange('A1').getValue();
  var days = 1
  var newdate = new Date();
  newdate.setDate(currdate.getDate() + days);
  ss.getRange('B1').setValue(newdate).setNumberFormat("dd/MM/yyyy");
};
```

Comment: It is not really what I was looking for, but I am sure i can use this in some way, thank you!

Comment: Please elaborate what you want exactly as the above code can add a day in the existing date of cell A1 and place the new date in cell B1.